# How does Graphite handle oversamples

Tags: graphite

I am trying to understand how Graphite treats over samples. I read the documentation but could not find the answer.

For example, If I specify in Graphite that the retention policy should be 1 sample in 60 seconds and graphite receives something like 200 values in 60 seconds, what will be stored exactly ? Will graphite take an average or a random point in those 200 points ?

Answer (score 2):

*Short answer*: it depends on the configuration, default is to take the last one.

*Long answer*, Graphite can configure, using regexp a strategy to aggregate several points in one sample.

These strategies are [configured](https://graphite.readthedocs.org/en/0.9.x/config-carbon.html#storage-aggregation-conf) in `storage-aggregations.conf` file, using regexp to select metrics:

```
[all_min]
pattern = \.min$
aggregationMethod = min
```

This example conf, will aggregate points using their minimum.

By default, the last point to arrive wins.

This strategy will always be used to aggregate from higher resolutions to lower resolutions.

For example, if storage-schemas.conf contains:

```
[all]
pattern = .*
retentions = 1s:8d,1h:1y
```

Given the sum aggregation method, all points arrived for the same second will be summed and stored with a second resolution.
Points older than 8 days will be summed again to one hour resolution.

Answer (score 0):

The aggregation configuration only applies when moving from archive i to archive i+1. For oversampling, it's always pick the last sample in the period.

The recommendation is to match sampling rate with the configuration.

see [graphite issue](https://github.com/graphite-project/carbon/issues/789#issuecomment-404565046)